# nginx limit client ssl certificate limit to location

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to set up a scenario with a lb nginx running as proxypass.
I am using client ssl certificates to be able to access different locations (for example /admin)

```
ssl_client_certificate subca-certicate.crt #subca
ssl_trusted_certificate ca-certificate.crt #ca

ssl_verify_deph 2

ssl_verify_client optional


location /admin
{
if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCESS) {return 401;}
}

location /
{
}
```

The problem is that if the browser does not have the certificate installed, it works correctly. in /admin it returns a 401 and in / it works correctly

But in the case that the browser does have the certificate, in / it asks for the certificate and even if you cancel it enters correctly

Is there another way to limit the /admin certificate the way Apache works, in nginx I couldn't find a way to do it.

get ssl client certificado with /admin en nginx